# Left floated element doesn't go upward

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I am practicing with float property and I currently have a html like this:

```css
section {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<section style="margin-left: 150px;"> </section>
<section style="height: 300px;"></section>
<section></section>
<section> </section>
<section style="height: 300px; width: 3px; background-color: blue;"></section>
```

The thing I don't get about this is that the last section element (the blue box) doesn't go  all the way up but instead is "fixed" a bit down. What is the reason and how can I fix this ? (Not linking fiddle because in fiddle the display is too small so it behaves differently.)

Comment: You could use negative top margin for the in-line CSS on the blue section, like this margin-top: -9%;

Comment: i guess your question is how float work ? as i don't see any issue in your code .

Comment: @TemaniAfif Actually it's an issue because float works by going as up as it can but this behaves differently for some other reason.

Comment: no this not how float works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it hapens becouse of the screen size.
Testing in my PC, when browser is fullscreen, all of the keeps on top. When I change the browser size to half screen, the blue section comes down.
Try use percentage to width.

Comment: Yeah but anyway why does it float down ? I mean it definitely has space.

Comment: In my tests, there are no space. Even becouse the first has an padding-left.
Try diminish the sections width.

Answer (score 0):

It likely is breaking to a new line with the last non-blue box, then the blue box starts on the same level. If you want to stack the boxes then you will need to use some extra divs.

Comment: How are extra divs helpful?

Comment: say you want to have three columns, with one or more styled boxes in each. You'd need to float the containing divs into columns. Floats just don't work the way you'd expect them to always. for a complicated masonry style layout its better to use flexbox. as long as you don't have to support IE 9 or below